# PHP $_POST from disabled input

Tags: php

I've got a quick question. Will disabled input post something when submitted?
Yes, I know there is a bad question but I need a quick help! Thanks!

Comment: Try google or by doing stuff.

Comment: No, it will not submit it

Answer (score -1):

No, disabled input will not post on submit.